# Hibernate entity - add business logic to entity?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, entity

I have entity:

```
@Entity(name = "Term")
@Table(name = "extra_term")
public class Term implements Cloneable, Serializable{
```

This entity has ID

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
```

And this entity has attribute with List of users owned by this entity (users are registered to term)

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "etc. etc. etc. })    
private List<TermUser> users = new ArrayList<TermUser>();
```

Is it possible to declare business method to count the sum of this users registered to concrete term? Something like

```
public long getUsersCount() {
  return QUERY TO THE DATABASE "GET COUNT OF USERS REGISTERED TO TERM WITH ID
  (where ID is the id of this entity?)"
}
```

I need to count the number of users registered to term straight from the entitz but I dont want to have a attribute "registeredUsersCount" in DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what [`@Transient`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-property) is for.

> Every non static non transient property (field or method depending on the access type) of an entity is considered persistent, unless you annotate it as @Transient.

Comment: Ok so I thing it will be something like this, right?  @Transient
 public long getCountOfRegisteredUsers() {
  return this.users.size();
 }

Comment: Yes since there is no field, you would just annotate the getter method.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I will read more in the official documentation.